# Rails using gitbash and ruby installer. rails command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git-bash

I am trying to get Ruby on Rails going on my Windows 7 machine. I am using gitbash and have install ruby using ruby installer. All my gems have installed successfully (Rails 3.0.7), but when I try to run a command like `rails s` I get `sh.exe": rails: command not found`

`echo $PATH` gives me:

`/c/Users/Dave/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Ruby192/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Adobe/AGL:/c/Program Files/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live`

Since the path for Ruby is in there I am at a bit of a loss for how to be able to start the rails server.

Comment: have you tried running `gem install rails`? http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby-on-rails/running-rails-3-on-windows/ seems like a proper guide, tough I havent had a go at ruby on windows for a while.

Comment: heh, yeah that is actually what I had to do. I thought it would work just from me doing bundle install, but for it to install the command I needed to do an explicit gem install even though it was already installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running gem install rails fixed it

Comment: Did you run that in the ruby console or in git bash?

Answer (score 1):

This Problem confuses basic developers. Because they simultaneously use both Git Bash & Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails.

When we type "Rails any command" in CMD with Ruby and Rails, we don't see any failure. But if we run the same command in gitbash means, we get the result "Command not found". Running "Gem install rails" fixs it for gitbash users as the above sayings.

For those who use both Git and Cmd with ROR, they can get the command executed anyhow by running on any of the one...